# Generic functions on Arrays in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I often work with arrays of int/float and other things on a regular basis in C# since they are faster (maybe?) than List. Currently I've got dozens of functions implemented per type:

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks if the array contains the given value.
/// </summary>
public static bool contains(int[] values, int value) {
    for (int s = 0, sl = values.Length; s < sl; s++) {
        if (values[s] == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
/// <summary>
/// Checks if the array contains the given value.
/// </summary>
public static bool contains(float[] values, float value) {
    for (int s = 0, sl = values.Length; s < sl; s++) {
        if (values[s] == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there a way to implement these in a generic way? Or is that only possible if I use `List<T>`?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? LINQ has this covered.

Comment: "(maybe?)"? You don't _know_ for certain? You really should be testing and benchmarking first.

Comment: Anything generic that you did would be slower.  If you care about the difference between an array and a list (which is **tiny**) you wouldn't want to deal with the (only slightly more than infintessimal) slowdown of genericizing this.

Comment: @Servy in what way would the generic version be slower? each generic function is jitted per type that it is used on so it ought to be exactly as fast as a non generic version. except for minimal differences upon jitting.

Comment: @RogerAlsing In general, you're correct, however in the specific case of dealing with numeric types, no.  There is no generic constraint that you could add (since the numeric types don't have interfaces for most of their functionality) that expose most of what they do.  You'll end up using `object.Equals` to compare the elements, or worse, using a `Func` to determine equality, which will be slower than having the parameter typed as i.e. `int` and using `operator ==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `System.Array` type has a dizzying array of static methods that can help you search, arrange, sort etc your arrays. You definitely do not need to roll your own. These static methods (like `Find`, `FindAll`) also accept generic arguments. Here's the list, dumped with the aid of PowerShell:

```
Name                           Definition                    
----                           ----------                    
AsReadOnly                     static System.Collections.... 
BinarySearch                   static int BinarySearch(ar... 
Clear                          static void Clear(array ar... 
ConstrainedCopy                static void ConstrainedCop... 
ConvertAll                     static TOutput[] ConvertAl... 
Copy                           static void Copy(array sou... 
CreateInstance                 static array CreateInstanc... 
Equals                         static bool Equals(System.... 
Exists                         static bool Exists[T](T[] ... 
Find                           static T Find[T](T[] array... 
FindAll                        static T[] FindAll[T](T[] ... 
FindIndex                      static int FindIndex[T](T[... 
FindLast                       static T FindLast[T](T[] a... 
FindLastIndex                  static int FindLastIndex[T... 
ForEach                        static void ForEach[T](T[]... 
IndexOf                        static int IndexOf(array a... 
LastIndexOf                    static int LastIndexOf(arr... 
ReferenceEquals                static bool ReferenceEqual... 
Resize                         static void Resize[T]([ref... 
Reverse                        static void Reverse(array ... 
Sort                           static void Sort(array arr... 
TrueForAll                     static bool TrueForAll[T](...
```

Comment: You call 20 functions a **dizzying array?** *(What if he saw my collection!)*

Comment: I was concentrating more on the pun on "array" than the method count ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Thanks @Servy for your corrections :**

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks if the array contains the given value.
/// </summary>
public static bool Contains<T>(T[] values, T value) {
    for (int s = 0, sl = values.Length; s < sl; s++) {
        if (object.Equals(values[s].value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For this kind of things, you may also use Linq :

```
using System.Linq;
...
var myArray = new float[12];
...
if(myArray.Any(a => a == 2.4))
```

Comment: This won't handle `null` objects well...  (unless you add a `where T:struct`)  If you use the static `object.Equals(a,b)` it will take care of that.

Comment: @Kek add a `where T : struct` generic constraint! ;)

Comment: @Geotarget That would do a reference comparison, not a value comparison, since an unconstrained `T` is equivalent to `object`.

Comment: @Servy, you are right... This is not perfect code, but adding a where T struct seems a little restrictive. I think it depends on how it is called. I'll let the OP customize this code

Comment: @Servy I see you like discussing... :D Because OP is using **value types** (int, float)... and adding such constraint would prevent specifying classes as type parameter.

Comment: @Kek See my edit.  Just use `object.Equals(a,b)` instead of `a.Equals(b)` and the null check will be properly handled.

Comment: `Array.Exists<T>` is a better choice that reimplementing the wheel. You guys are getting caught up in the academics of an implementation when something built-in already exists ;)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer True, it will handle the current cases fine, but the method has no real need to be constrained to structs in general, so why go out of your way to prevent future use of the function for class types?  If allowing them to work was a significant change, I'd say wait until you think you'll need it, but not doing work to make a method *more* flexible seems appropriate.

Comment: @x0n That's true, but OP question is more general than just this "contains" method. He's talking about dozens of methods. So giving a fish is good... learning how to fish sounds better